# Select statement with conditions depending on the value of another column - same table (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have table with 3 columns:

```
ID, 
Cancellation_Policy_Type 
Cancellation_Policy_Hours.
```

The query I would like to get to will allow me to select:

- the min Cancellation_Policy_Hours which correspond to the Free Cancellation (if exists)
- if the above doesn't exist for the specific ID, then I want to check if there is a partially refundable
- if none of the above exist, then check if there is No Refundable.

The below query is not correct but it may give a better idea about what I am trying to achieve:

```
IF (SELECT ID, Cancellation_Policy_Type, MIN(Cancellation_Policy_Hours) from MYTABLE WHERE Cancellation_Policy_Type = 'Free Cancellation') IS NOT NULL)
THEN (SELECT ID, Cancellation_Policy_Type, MIN(Cancellation_Policy_Hours) from MYTABLE WHERE Cancellation_Policy_Type = 'Free Cancellation')
ELSEIF (SELECT ID, Cancellation_Policy_Type, MIN(Cancellation_Policy_Hours) from MYTABLE WHERE Cancellation_Policy_Type = 'Free Cancellation') IS NULL AND (SELECT ID, Cancellation_Policy_Type, MIN(Cancellation_Policy_Hours  from MYTABLE WHERE Cancellation_Policy_Type = 'Partially Refundable') IS NOT NULL Then (SELECT ID, Cancellation_Policy_Type, MIN(Cancellation_Policy_Hours) from MYTABLE WHERE Cancellation_Policy_Type = 'Partially Refundable')
ELSEIF (SELECT ID, Cancellation_Policy_Type, MIN(Cancellation_Policy_Hours) from MYTABLE WHERE Cancellation_Policy_Type = 'Free Cancellation') IS NULL AND (SELECT ID, Cancellation_Policy_Type, MIN(Cancellation_Policy_Hours) from MYTABLE WHERE Cancellation_Policy_Type = 'Partially Refundable') IS NULL  THEN (SELECT ID, Cancellation_Policy_Type, MIN(Cancellation_Policy_Hours) from MYTABLE WHERE Cancellation_Policy_Type = 'No Refundable') 
END
```

Below you will find an example of my dataset:

This is the table which contains all data regarding the cancellation policies of every single ID:

| ID | Cancellation_Policy_Type | Cancellation_Policy_Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | No Refundable | 17520 |
| 1 | Partially Refunable | 168 |
| 1 | Free Cancellation | 96 |
| 2 | No Refundable | 17520 |
| 2 | Partially Refunable | 336 |
| 2 | Free Cancellation | 48 |
| 3 | No Refundable | 17520 |
| 3 | Partially Refunable | 336 |
| 4 | No Refundable | 17520 |

Below is the desired result, that is a table which contains other pieces of information (including production) and the 2 columns where for every single ID repeats the best available cancellation policy type and hours:

| ID | Most Flexible Cancellation Type | Most Flexible Cancellation Hours | Other Columns (including buckets) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Free Cancellation | 96 | a |
| 1 | Free Cancellation | 96 | b |
| 1 | Free Cancellation | 96 | c |
| 2 | Free Cancellation | 48 | a |
| 2 | Free Cancellation | 48 | b |
| 2 | Free Cancellation | 48 | c |
| 3 | Partially Refunable | 336 | a |
| 3 | Partially Refunable | 336 | b |
| 3 | Partially Refunable | 336 | c |
| 4 | No Refundable | 17520 | a |
| 4 | No Refundable | 17520 | b |
| 4 | No Refundable | 17520 | c |

```
SELECT
a.ID
, Most_Flexible_Policy_Type 
, Most_Flexible_Cancellation_Hours
, a.BookingWindowBuckets
FROM Production a
LEFT JOIN Property b on a.ID = b.ID
GROUP BY
1,2,3,4
```

Thank you

Comment: It would help if you explain what table the "other columns" are coming from and what the relationship is to MYTABLE. When including sample data [use tables](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post), not images. The images may look nice but anyone wanting to test an answer before posting it will not be able to copy the data.

Comment: I have shared a simplified version of the query. The main point of the question is: how can I get the best cancellation policy and policy hours for every single ID and use only them to populate the columns  Most_Flexible_Policy_Type and  Most_Flexible_Cancellation_Hours by ID?

Comment: What is the typical distribution in the Property table (1 per ID per type or 1k per ID per type)? What version of MySQL are you using? Please update your question with tables instead of images, as previously suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that, for each row in `production`, you want to bring from table `property` the cancellation policy with the least policy hours.

We can do this with window functions to rank the policies of feach `id`, and a join to `production`:

```
select d.id, 
    p.cancellation_type_policy  most_flexible_cancellation_type,
    p.cancellation_policy_hours most_flexible_cancellation_hours
from production d
inner join (
    select p.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by cancellation_policy_hours) rn
    from property p
) p on p.id = d.id
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not given enough information to be able to help you with any degree of confidence that it is the "right" way but (guessing here) you could try -

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MIN(IF(Cancellation_Policy_Type = 'Free Cancellation', Cancellation_Policy_Hours, NULL)) AS minFreeCancellation,
    MIN(IF(Cancellation_Policy_Type = 'Partially Refundable', Cancellation_Policy_Hours, NULL)) AS minPartiallyRefundable,
    MIN(IF(Cancellation_Policy_Type = 'No Refundable', Cancellation_Policy_Hours, NULL)) AS minNoRefundable
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE ID = ?
GROUP BY ID;
```

If you provide an example in the form of full table structure (CREATE statement), some sample data, some stats and the desired outcome you are more likely to get the "right" answer. The above example of conditional aggregation is unlikely to be the best way to do it but it will probably provide what you are looking for. Depending on your dataset, just running the separate queries may be the best solution.

**UPDATE**
Here is one way of doing this using a window function (MySQL 8) -

```
WITH Properties (ID, Cancellation_Policy_Type, Cancellation_Policy_Hours, Most_Flexible) AS (
    SELECT
        ID, Cancellation_Policy_Type, Cancellation_Policy_Hours,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY
            CASE Cancellation_Policy_Type
                WHEN 'Free Cancellation' THEN 0
                WHEN 'Partially Refundable' THEN 1
                WHEN 'No Refundable' THEN 2
            END ASC, Cancellation_Policy_Hours ASC
        )
    FROM Property
)
SELECT
    a.ID,
    b.Cancellation_Policy_Type,
    b.Cancellation_Policy_Hours,
    a.BookingWindowBuckets
FROM Production a
LEFT JOIN Properties b on a.ID = b.ID
WHERE b.Most_Flexible = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you @nnichols, I edited by question with more details as you suggested.

Comment: Hi thank you so much! As per GMB,  for each row in production, I need to bring from table property the cancellation policy with the least policy hours and associated policy type.

Comment: I clearly misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted to order by Cancellation_Policy_Type first and then hours. Glad you got the answer you need.